# JQuery Mobile popup appears focused on (at least) Lenovo p780

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, android-browser

I've found this bug when testing my Phonegap app on Lenovo p780 (4.2.1 stock rom).

It's absent on Android emulators (4.3, 4.2.2, 2.3.3), Lenovo p700i (4.0.4 stock rom), Huawei Honor U8860 (4.0.4 custom rom).

1. After popping out
2. After orientation change
3. After tap on popup (how it should look like)

[image] [image] [image]

Is there any fix or workaround for that (I've tried to use Panel instead of Popup, but it looks strange with only 3 buttons)? Have you encountered it on other devices or it's just gift from Lenovo?